# Bootstrap: extra width on exact same div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to fix a peculiar problem I'm having in Bootstrap 3. It's my first time using it, so maybe I'm missing something.

Basically, at the bottom of my page I have a news section which is correctly displayed on all but "extra small" devices.

This is how it looks on small to large devices:
[image: Large device]

And this is what it looks like on an extra small device:
[image: Extra small device]

As you can see, the top div is now larger than the bottom ones, for no apparent reason (I think). It is 30 pixels wider.

Even when removing all of the blue div's content, it remains wider, so it's not the elements inside.

Here's my HTML:

```
  <div class="row rowspacer">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="news-help bs-callout bs-callout-blueborder col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
        <h4><i class="fa fa-globe"></i>&nbsp;News</h4>
        <span class="small news-subtitle">from us</span>
        <form class="form-articles">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="sel1">Number of articles:</label>
            <select class="form-control" id="sel1">
              <option value="3">3</option>
              <option value="5">5</option>
              <option value="10">10</option>
              <option value="all">Alle</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="news-wrapper col-md-9 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
        <div class="bs-callout bs-callout-danger">
          <h4>New order mechanism!</h4>
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam, minus, eum quam adipisci saepe, unde asperiores nesciunt blanditiis similique nisi explicabo. Deserunt alias maxime nemo cupiditate, veritatis recusandae quasi nostrum.
          </p>
          <p class="small">01/09/2015</p>
        </div>
        <div class="bs-callout bs-callout-danger">
          <h4>Open every day in August</h4>
          <p>
             Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Enim consectetur, voluptatibus maiores totam delectus tempora exercitationem ad numquam, cupiditate, nisi quo expedita veniam repudiandae! Nam ipsum aperiam, recusandae maiores at.
          </p>
          <p class="small">01/08/2015</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

And here's my (relevant) CSS:

```
.rowspacer {
  margin-top: 40px;
}

.bs-callout {
  -moz-border-bottom-colors: none;
  -moz-border-left-colors: none;
  -moz-border-right-colors: none;
  -moz-border-top-colors: none;
  /*border-color: #eee;*/
  border-color: #E1E1E1;
  border-image: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px 1px 1px 5px;
  margin-bottom: 7px;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.bs-callout-danger {
  border-left-color: #d9534f;
}

.bs-callout-blueborder {
  border-left-color: #325d88;
}

.news-subtitle {
  margin-left: 19px;
}

.form-articles {
  margin-top: 22px;
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `bs-callout` markup isn't consistent. Your first callout *is* the bootstrap column, whereas the other 2 are descendants of their column.

Put your first callout within the column, as a new element:

```
<div class="row rowspacer">
<div class="container">
  <div class="news-help col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
    <div class="bs-callout bs-callout-blueborder"> <!-- Here -->
      <h4><i class="fa fa-globe"></i>&nbsp;News</h4>
      <span class="small news-subtitle">from us</span>
      <form class="form-articles">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="sel1">Number of articles:</label>
          <select class="form-control" id="sel1">
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
            <option value="10">10</option>
            <option value="all">Alle</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div> <!-- /Here -->
  </div>
  <div class="news-wrapper col-md-9 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
    <div class="bs-callout bs-callout-danger">
      <h4>New order mechanism!</h4>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam, minus, eum quam adipisci saepe, unde asperiores nesciunt blanditiis similique nisi explicabo. Deserunt alias maxime nemo cupiditate, veritatis recusandae quasi nostrum.
      </p>
      <p class="small">01/09/2015</p>
    </div>
    <div class="bs-callout bs-callout-danger">
      <h4>Open every day in August</h4>
      <p>
         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Enim consectetur, voluptatibus maiores totam delectus tempora exercitationem ad numquam, cupiditate, nisi quo expedita veniam repudiandae! Nam ipsum aperiam, recusandae maiores at.
      </p>
      <p class="small">01/08/2015</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/oGeez/zxxpjznu/)

Comment: And I thought I had a "special" problem :). Thanks

Comment: @Michiel No problem :)

Answer (score 0):

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ishimdar/evjdwwt0/)

```
<div class="row rowspacer">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="news-help bs-callout bs-callout-blueborder col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
        <h4><i class="fa fa-globe"></i>&nbsp;News</h4>
        <span class="small news-subtitle">from us</span>
        <form class="form-articles">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="sel1">Number of articles:</label>
            <select class="form-control" id="sel1">
              <option value="3">3</option>
              <option value="5">5</option>
              <option value="10">10</option>
              <option value="all">Alle</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="news-wrapper col-md-9 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
        <div class="bs-callout bs-callout-danger">
          <h4>New order mechanism!</h4>
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam, minus, eum quam adipisci saepe, unde asperiores nesciunt blanditiis similique nisi explicabo. Deserunt alias maxime nemo cupiditate, veritatis recusandae quasi nostrum.
          </p>
          <p class="small">01/09/2015</p>
        </div>
        <div class="bs-callout bs-callout-danger">
          <h4>Open every day in August</h4>
          <p>
             Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Enim consectetur, voluptatibus maiores totam delectus tempora exercitationem ad numquam, cupiditate, nisi quo expedita veniam repudiandae! Nam ipsum aperiam, recusandae maiores at.
          </p>
          <p class="small">01/08/2015</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Css

```
.rowspacer {
  margin-top: 40px;
}

.bs-callout {
  -moz-border-bottom-colors: none;
  -moz-border-left-colors: none;
  -moz-border-right-colors: none;
  -moz-border-top-colors: none;
  /*border-color: #eee;*/
  border-color: #E1E1E1;
  border-image: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px 1px 1px 5px;
  margin-bottom: 7px;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.bs-callout-danger {
  border-left-color: #d9534f;
}

.bs-callout-blueborder {
  border-left-color: #325d88;
}

.news-subtitle {
  margin-left: 19px;
}

.form-articles {
  margin-top: 22px;
}
```